# jQuery Mobile form not working

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using current versions of jQuery:

```html
<!--jQuery-->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--jQuery UI-->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<!--jQuery Mobile-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://
```

I have the following HTML (which I copy-pasted from docs to ensure correctness):

```html
<div id="form-pay" data-role="fieldcontain">
    <form action="mailer.php" method="post">
        <label for="basic">Text Input:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="basic" data-mini="true" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Everything is working fine with buttons, accordions and animations, but for some reason forms like the above are not working. They just show up unstyled. Is there any initialization I need to do? The docs say forms are auto-initialized.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: JQM recommends the below CDN-hosted files. Replace them with the ones you have and try again. If the problem persists, post your complete code.<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

**[jQuery Mobile 1.2 (1.2.0) works with versions of jQuery core from 1.7.0 to 1.8.2.](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/about/getting-started.html)**

Therefore change jQuery to ver 1.8.2 (or 1.8.3)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/5CGKk/)

or use jQuery migrate if you for some reason need ver.1.9.X

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/S52Fw/)